# Ranking values based on two columns

Tags: python, ranking

I'm trying to devise a way to rank accounts from best to worst based on their telephone duration and margin.

The data looks like this;

```
ID  TIME_ON_PHONE  MARGIN
1   1235           1256
2   12             124 
3   1635           0
4   124            652
5   0              4566
```

Any suggestions on how to rank them from best to worst?

ID 5 = best as we have spent no time on the phone but their margin is the most.

ID 3 = worst as we've spend ages on the phone but no orders.

I've put it into excel to try and devise a solution but I can't get the ranking correct.

Comment: It's unclear what sorting criterion you are looking for exactly. You should add the required output and explain its logic.

Comment: We can help you with codings, but we can not decide for you what logic you want to use. But maybe `MARGIN` - 'TIME_ON_PHONE` is good for you.

Comment: You can sort by the `margin / time_on_phone` ratio, and make the ratio `float('inf')` in case `time_on_phone` is `0`.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin with the logic!!! The code I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new metric like

**New Metric = Margin / Time on phone**

to compare each row.

To create a column with this metric just use:

```
dataframe["new_metric"] = dataframe["MARGIN"]/dataframe["TIME_ON_PHONE"]
```

Having 0 values in the TIME_ON_PHONE column will lead to an error, so I recommend replacing those values with a very small one, like 0.001 or something.

After that you can simply use this line of code to sort your rows:

```
dataframe = dataframe.sort_values("new_metric", ascending = False)
```

That way you would end up with the first ID being the best one, the second ID the second best one... etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That works enough for me to get something out of it, thanks. its the 0.0001 bit thats solved it for me!! Thank you